# Displaying Wordpress custom post type by first letter with Timber (twig)

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I use Timber for Wordpress and I would like to create a dictionary system like that :
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119163/displaying-custom-post-type-by-first-letter-through-custom-taxonomy

I wrote this :

**lexique.php**

```
$query = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'lexique','posts_per_page' => -1));
```

But I don't know how to transform this with Timber :

```
$by_letter = array();
while( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
  global $post;
  $letter = substr($post->post_name, 0, 1);
  if ( ! isset($by_letter[$letter]) ) $by_letter[$letter] = array();
  $by_letter[$letter][] = $post;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: You should avoid doing a `substr()` it's intensive, a better way would be to use `terms` and then with one query using `$wpdb` you can select all custom posts and order by term.

Comment: @Erevald, thank you but I can use this loop in Timber ?

Comment: Put the loop in a function in your theme and in your `twig` file you can show it like this `{{function("mytheme_loop_function")}}`

Comment: How to use terms and $wpdb please ?

Comment: I have no idea how introducing `terms` would make a solution any easier. The way to use timber is not to call a function in your Twig file that uses The Loop again. You use Timber because you want to get rid of The Loop.

Comment: @Gchtr doing hundreds or more of `substr()` would probably be intensive for the server. Also having a custom taxonomy will give you an archive page for each term ex. `blog.com/lexicon/a`.

Comment: @Erevald Okay, I see how terms might be a good addition if you want to have separate index pages for each letter. This could also be accomplished with [Timber’s routing system](http://timber.github.io/timber/#routing), where you then use the letter to adapt the main query.
What would you recommend instead of `substr`? Accessing the first letter through `$post->post_title[0]`?

Comment: @Gchtr, I see the routes on Timber but without terms you wouldn't be able to query by certain letter. If the post titles first letter is always latin then it's safe to use `$string[0]` it's faster than doing `substr`.

Comment: @Erevald Yeah, you’re right, I forgot that you can’t query by a starting letter. The filtering would have to be done after a query for all the posts, which is not nice. So terms are the way to go! What would be good then is to set a hook that auto-assign the correct term when saving a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a good idea to get all posts at once. By adding the `orderby` parameter, you can already put them into the correct order for the letter-sorting. I’d use `title` and not `name` for the sorting and to define the first letter, because `name`/`post_name` is a URL-safe string (used in permalinks) might be different from the actual title of the post.

You get the posts through `Timber::get_posts()`, so that you don’t have to rely on The Loop. You get an array with posts that you can work with, before you render it through a Twig file. This is much more direct than the method you linked to, because you **don’t** have to rely on additional functions and query resets.

**lexique.php**

```
$posts = Timber::get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'lexique',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
) );

$posts_by_letter = array();

// Sort posts by letter
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    $first_letter = substr( $post->post_title, 0, 1);

    // Create array for letter if it doesn’t exist
    if ( ! isset( $posts_by_letter[ $first_letter ] ) ) {
        $posts_by_letter[ $first_letter ] = array();
    }

    $posts_by_letter[ $first_letter ][] = $post;
}

$context['posts_by_letter'] = $posts_by_letter;

Timber::render( [ 'lexique.twig' ], $context );
```

### Display only letters for existing posts

**lexique.twig**

```
<dl>
{% for letter, posts in posts_by_letter %}
    <dt>{{ letter }}</dt>

    {% for post in posts  %}
        <dd><a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ post.title }}</a></dd>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</dl>
```

Because you have a nested array, you have to do two for-loops. The first loop goes through the letters (which are the keys of the outer array). The value assigned to a letter key is another array, containing all the posts starting with that letter. To display the post titles as links, you use the second for-loop.

### Display all letters from A to Z

If you want to generate a list of all letters from A to Z and display existing posts, you can use `range` and check if posts exists for that letter in `posts_by_letter`.

Additionally you can use `range` to create a list of anchor links that lets a visitor jump to a specific letter.

**lexique.twig**

```
 {# Anchor links to jump to letter #}
 {% for letter in range('A', 'Z') %}
     <a href="#{{ letter }}">{{ letter }}</a>
 {% endfor %}

 <dl>
 {% for letter in range('A', 'Z') %}
     <dt><a id="{{ letter }}">{{ letter }}</a></dt>
     {% if posts_by_letter[letter] is defined %}
         {% for post in posts_by_letter[letter]  %}
             <dd><a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ post.title }}</a></dd>
         {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 </dl>
```

Comment: Wow ! This is juste perfect ! This was exactly what I needed ! Thank a lot ! But I have a problem, I would like to generate a list of letters A, B, C, D... with anchors but all the letters don't appears. A create only words for A and B for the moment but I would like to have all the letters, is it possible ?

Comment: I created only words for A and B for the moment, so in my letters list A, B, C.. I only have A and B. Is it possible to have all letter (even empty) ? I saw something like $keys = range('a', 'z'); but how to use it ?

Comment: @Jandon Yes, it’s possible to display all the letters from A to Z and show posts when they exist. I updated the answer with a solution for this.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's work perfectly ! Thank you to have commented your code, I understand how that's work now. I try to had a condition to change the href if a letter is empty, but that don't work {% if letter is empty %} <li><a href="#">{{letter}}</a></li> {% else %} <li><a href="#{{letter}}">{{letter}}</a></li> {% endif %}

Comment: @Jandon `{{ letter }}` itself will never be empty. You’ll want to check whether posts exist that start with that letter. Try with `{% if posts_by_letter[letter] is not empty %}`.